# how to call the default voice recorder app programmatically for android phone?

Tags: android, audio-recording, voice-recording

i'm trying to create an app that allows voice recording. i hope to call the default voice recorder app just like how i call the camera app. what i wanted is my app will intent/call the default app. after recording, it will return immediately to my app (just like what happen when i call for the camera)

the code that i used for calling the camera :

```
Intent takePictureFromCameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

is there anyway that is close to the code above, where its simple and also achieved what i wanted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
Intent recordIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
startActivityForResult(recordIntent, RESULT_OK);
```

And onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
  {
    String theFilePath = data.getData().toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: it does open the app, but how do i specify where it save ? because the camera one could save it using 

Uri mUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Record/cam_"+ String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

takePictureFromCameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);

Comment: it doesnt work. the recording is safe to the default folder rather then the folder i placed. thks anyway. i will ask another question for it.

Comment: Thanks user370305. One more request, is that possible to supply some arguments such as 10 seconds and then the recorder should record voice not more then 10 seconds.

Comment: @Gem you can specify this by putting max size extra
`recordIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MAX_BYTES,180  * 1024L * 1024L);`
This should correspond to 1 hour.You can play with it to reach 10 seconds